# Ansible jinja filter out elements with attribute not equal to something OR attribute missing

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, jinja2

I have some tasks like this:

```
- ec2_asg_facts:
    region: us-west-2
    tags:
      Name: my-asg
  register: asg
- set_fact:
    current_lc: "{{ asg.results | map(attribute='launch_configuration_name') | first }}"
    instances: "{{ asg.results | map(attribute='instances') | flatten | list }}"
- set_fact:
    instances_to_rotate: "{{ instances | rejectattr('launch_configuration_name', 'equalto', current_lc) | list }}"
```

The problem is that if the launch configuration for the instances is deleted (which is often the case when I am updating the launch config for the ASG to a new one, but haven't yet terminated the old instances) the `launch_configuration_name` attribute is missing, so the third task fails with the message `'dict object' has no attribute 'launch_configuration_name'`. How can I filter out items in the `instances` list that have the `launch_configuration_name` attribute not equal to `current_lc` OR have the `launch_configuration_name` attribute missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is to filter in two passes; first filter out the items where the attribute is undefined, then filter out the ones where the attribute is not equal to `current_lc`.

```
- set_fact:
    instances_to_rotate: "{{ instances | rejectattr('launch_configuration_name', 'undefined') | rejectattr('launch_configuration_name', 'equalto', current_lc) | list }}"
```

Comment: where can i get more information like using equalto in the rejectattr. the jinja documentation is not informative enough for me.

Comment: @user3980196 To be honest, I don't use jinja directly anymore, I always use it through ansible. So sometimes I forget whether a filter is in stock jinja or if it's an ansible addition. If you don't find it in the jinja docs, then check [ansible's docs on their extra filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html).